# Change VS2005 default debug window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

When I load up my MFC C++ app in VS2005, the IDE always defaults to the command window. How do I make it switch to the Output or Immediate windows by default?

Answer (score 0):

These windows (command, output, find results et cetera) are docked in 1 with tabs. What I did was shift the tabs around (I put Output leftmost both in IDE and debugger) and after a while it stayed that way :) (closed & reloaded VS to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

These windows are set to specific defaults but if you move them around they should persist their new locations between debugging sessions.  This is definitely the case in VS2008 and beyond.  I don't have a copy of VS2005 handy to test this out though.